# keydown function not enabling alert function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code right now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("div#main-edit").click( function() {
var cursorExists = $("input#cursor").length;
if (cursorExists == false){
   $("div#cursor-start").append("<input type='text' id = 'cursor' />");
   $("input#cursor").focus();
  }

});


  $("input#cursor").keydown(function() {
  $("div#cursor-start").enterText();
});

jQuery.fn.enterText = function(){
    alert("hello");
};

});
```

The function enterText is not called in this situation though. It seems like the fix should be easy for this. Is it because jquery finds nothing to select (input#cursor) when the document loads up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code has problems because you are calling this;

```
$("input#cursor").keydown(function() {
  $("div#cursor-start").enterText();
});
```

before the object `input#cursor` has been created by your code.  Thus, it won't find the object and can't install an event handler for it.  I would suggest you change your code to this which installs the event handler only after the object is created:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div#main-edit").click( function() {
        var cursorExists = $("input#cursor").length;
        if (cursorExists == false) {
            $("div#cursor-start").append("<input type='text' id = 'cursor' />");
            $("input#cursor").focus();
            // install event handler, now that we know the object exists
            $("input#cursor").keydown(function() {
                $("div#cursor-start").enterText();
            });
        }
    });

    jQuery.fn.enterText = function(){
        alert("hello");
    };
});
```

The alternative would be to use `.live("keydown", function() {})` instead of `.keydown()` which allows you to install some event handlers before the object exists (you can read the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/) on it to understand further).

FYI, you get a lot worse performance in jQuery when you use selectors like "input#cursor" instead of just "#cursor".  The latter gets optimized to use document.getElementById().  The former does not and takes a much longer code path.  Since there is only one object in the page with any given ID, there should be no reason to quality it with the tag type.  Just use "#main-edit", not "div#main-edit".

Comment: ya ...how could I call it..only if it exists..thats my problem

Comment: See what I added to my answer.  Install the event handler right after you create the object.

Comment: interesting...how would jquery trigger the event when the keydown is within the if block, since the condition becomes true.....

Comment: The if block only decides whether to create the cursor object and then initialize it with the keydown event handler.  Once the if block has executed, the keydown event handler is just this: `function() {
                $("div#cursor-start").enterText();
            });` and it doesn't matter that it happens to be located inside that if statement.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Checking an int (.length) against false doesn't make a whole lot of sense, even if JS will allow you to do it. It should be `$("input#cursor").length == 0)`

Have you tried just an `alert('hello')` inside of the keydown function, just to make sure it works? What about `alert($("div#cursor-start").length)`. If that's 0 then your selector is bad.

Simplify your script down to the bare bones until you find the problem. It's most likely a bad selector.

Comment: $("input#cursor").keydown(function() {
  alert("hello");
}); does not work either

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like that selector is bad. You should probably figure out why.